# Map right alt to left arrow on MacBook Pro with Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, macintosh, xkb, xcape

I’ve just created a Kali Linux partition on my MacBook Pro. On Mac OS I used [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap the right alt key to left arrow because my real left arrow key is broken.

Now I want to do the same thing on Kali. To do so I installed [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape). I tried several commands like `xcape -e "Alt_R=Left"` and `xcape -e "Alt_R=leftarrow"` but none of them modified the keymapping. I also considered to accomplish the key remapping by modifying the xkb files, but I'm unsure which entries in the files I have to modify. I would appreciate any help on remapping the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following command I was able to map left arrow on right alt:

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 108=Left'`

Afterwards I mapped AltGr on right command:

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 134=ISO_Level3_Shift'`